# CSS Code for fluid coloured Rectangle not working

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on my Portfolio Website with Semplice.

I have a specific Layout in mind and for that I need to use CSS Codes. I have never written a code in my life and am trying to learn how to write one.

For this specific example I want a fluid coloured square in the background.

This is the code I have been trying to make work:

```
.rectangle-box{
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #D3D3D3;
}
.rectangle-box:before{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 50%;
}
.rectangle-content{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50;
  left: 50;
  bottom: 50;
  right: 50;
  color: light grey;
}
.rectangle-content div {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Appreciate any help!

Thank you,
Sophie

Comment: `color: light grey;` => `color: lightgrey;`

Comment: share your html as well.

Comment: also, `top: 50;` => `top: 50px;` etc.

Comment: <div class='rectangle-box'>
    <div class='rectangle-content'><div><span>I'm a responsive CSS rectangle! Resize the window to see how I keep my aspect ratio.</span></div></div>
</div>

Comment: Original CSS:

.rectangle-box{
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #4679BD;
}
.rectangle-box:before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 50%;
}
.rectangle-content{
    position:  absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    color: white;
}
.rectangle-content div {
   display: table;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
.rectangle-content span {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: white
}

Comment: you need the background square or rectangle shape ?

Comment: I need a coloured Square which is fluid in the Background.